# Unable to trigger custom validation function on a FilteringSelect input

Tags: javascript, validation, dojo, dijit.form

The following code works for a textbox , I am able to override the default validator function with my own and force it to `return false`, making the input invalid.  However this does not work at all with `FilteringSelect` inputs.  The following code always returns true - in fact it never enters my custom validation function.

Which means it is executing a different validator than expected, OR I am setting the validator on the wrong input (there are multiple when rendered).

```
var customValidator = function (value) {
    console.log("custom validator: ", value);
    return false;  //force an invalid result
};

formelement.theInput.set('validator', customValidator);

var res = formelement.theInput.validate();
console.log("res: ", res);
```

The widget template looks lke this

```
<div data-dojo-attach-point="formelement"  >
    <select data-dojo-type="dijit/form/FilteringSelect" data-dojo-attach-point="theInput" 
            data-dojo-props="labelAttr:'text', searchAttr:'text', required:false, "   >
    </select>
</div>
```

Which when rendered looks like this

```
<div data-dojo-attach-point="formelement" style="position: absolute; left: 222px; top: 75px; width: 200px; border-width: 1px; border-style: none; border-color: black;" class="fe-dropdown resize-handle" id="4180a54b-3931-472e-8c5f-212bfddc88b2" widgetid="uniqName_10_10">
    <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft fe-element dijitTextBox dijitComboBox dijitValidationTextBox dijitTextBoxFocused dijitComboBoxFocused dijitValidationTextBoxFocused dijitFocused" id="widget_dijit_form_FilteringSelect_28" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" data-dojo-attach-point="_popupStateNode" widgetid="dijit_form_FilteringSelect_28" aria-disabled="false" popupactive="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="dijit_form_FilteringSelect_28_popup">
    <div class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode" role="presentation">
        <input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" value="▼ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="button presentation" aria-hidden="true">
    </div>
    <div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer">
        <input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation">
    </div>
    <div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer">
        <input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" type="text" autocomplete="off" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="both" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_FilteringSelect_28" aria-required="false" value="" aria-invalid="false" maxlength="25" style="font-family: Arial; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; color: black; text-decoration: none; text-align: left; background-color: transparent;">
        <input type="hidden" value="CA">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ithink this due to `isValid` function , it is overrided in the  FilteringSelect , so it wont have same behaviour as the textBox .

What I suggest is to ovveride the isValid again , after setting your custom validator as bellow :

```
formelement.theInput.isValid = 
    function() {
          return this.validator(this.textbox.value,this.get('constraints')); 
         // force new validator above 
    }
```

Bellow is a sample snippet:

```js
require(["dijit/registry", "dijit/form/FilteringSelect","dojo/on","dijit/form/Button","dojo/ready"],
  function(registry,dom,On,Button,ready){
      ready(function(){
          var customValidator = function (value) {
              console.log("custom validator: ", value);
              return false;  //force an invalid result
          };
          formelement = registry.byId("formelement");
          formelement.set('validator', customValidator);
          
          formelement.isValid = function() {
            return this.validator(this.textbox.value, this.get('constraints'));}

          var res = formelement.validate();
          console.log("res: ", res);
          
          var btn = registry.byId("btn");
          On(btn,"click",function(){
            console.log(formelement.validate());
          });
        })
    });
```

```html
<script>
dojoConfig = {
  isDebug: true,
  parseOnLoad: true,
};
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body class="claro">
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="btn"> Validate </div>
<div data-dojo-attach-point="formelement"  >
    <select id="formelement" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/FilteringSelect" data-dojo-attach-point="theInput" 
            data-dojo-props="labelAttr:'text', searchAttr:'text', required:false, "   >
    </select>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: does it make sense ?

Comment: interesting use of validator

Comment: I tested this code and yes this worked (for all input types that use validator, textbox, filteringselect, numbertextbox, etc), thank you.